# What's the best way to degrade gracefully when using a Plugin Variable?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, variable

When providing plugin users with variable containing arguments like `{{ craft.pluginname.variable(arg1, arg2) }}` what's the best practice for returning something that doesn't throw an Internal Server Error exception for Missing argument 1 or argument 2?

Should this be done as part of the /services/PluginService.php or somewhere else? Is it better to return a nicer Javascript console error (or Craft error log) vs. crashing the page?

Comment: I assume both arg1 and arg2 are required?

Comment: @BradBell - lets say yes. If not set, I'd like to return a nice "no options set" error and an empty output vs. the Internal Server Error crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be in your `PluginHandleVariable` file's method, just have it accept one, optional parameter and expect it to be an array.

```
public function variableMethod($options = null)
{
    if (!$options || !is_array($options))
    {
        return "No options set";
    }

    // Now you can check for individual options on the array
    if (isset($options['option1'])
    {
        ....
    }

}
```

Then both of these would work:

```
if craft.pluginname.variable()
if craft.pluginname.variable(options)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is defined` twig expression to determine if a variable is defined or not. Something like this:

```
{% if craft.pluginname.variable(arg1, arg2) is defined %}
    {{ craft.pluginname.variable(arg1, arg2) }}
{% elseif %}
    <p class="notice">Display notice.</p>.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry. I wrote this before reading the comments above.

Comment: This is good but I'd like it to be self contained within the plugin so you would only need to include {{ craft.pluginname.variable(arg1, arg2) }}